# Python to exe not working in different Machine- Getting error "Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually."

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pyinstaller, exe

I converted my Python code file to exe using pyinstaller --onefile. This exe is working correctly in my machine but when my teammate is running it into his machine with same input file, he is getting error "Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually".

Code: It reads an excel file using pandas.read_excel(), performs operations and outputs an excel file. Does anyone knows what can be the issue?

Note: Issue is not related to file extension, he is reading xlsx file

Comment: Probably in `Read_Excel` you need to explicitly declare the Engine you want to use. The default is openpyxl. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: @Warcupine , I already tried it, didn't worked. The exe is a --onefile, if it is working fine in my system it should run in his system as well, this is how --onefile exe is supposed to work. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, it will still search through the path to make any connections it needs to. Onefile combines everything into a single executable instead of a distribution folder with an exe inside that, but all the dependencies would be separate.